# scanf("%[^\n]s", fullName); kills my program

Tags: c, scanf

I beginner and need some help with scanf. I'm developing a bank app with C and every time I try to read the full name with spaces of stdin, my program just kills it self without prior warning and gcc doesn't give me any error while compiling.

To be specific, this happens when I try to use this:
`scanf("%[^\n]s", fullName);`
instead of this `scanf("%s", fullName);`

My problem is the white space.

```
// Libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Declaration of methods
void header(void);
void menu(void);
int manage(void);
void createAcc(void);

// Declaration of vars
int menuOption;
int manageOption;

// Main method
int main(void)
{
    // Clear console
    //system("clear");
    // Calls header and menu (just text), asks for an option at menu an assign it to menuOption var.
    header();
    menu();
    scanf("%d", &menuOption);

    // Check the option choose and run code
    switch (menuOption)
    {
    case 1:
        manage();
        break;
    
    default:
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Header method
void header(void)
{
    printf("\n\t\t\t\tC Bank\n");
    printf("\t\t\tChoose your option.\n");
}

// Menu method
void menu(void)
{
    printf("\n\t\t\t[1] Manage accounts.\n");
}

// Manage account method
int manage(void)
{
    // Create
    // Read
    // Update
    // Delete
    //system("clear");
    header();
    printf("\n");
    printf("\t\t\t[1] Create account.\n");
    printf("\t\t\t[2] Update account.\n");
    printf("\t\t\t[3] Delete account.\n");
    printf("\t\t\t[4] List all accounts.\n");
    printf("\t\t\t[5] Return to main menu.\n");
    scanf("%d", &manageOption);

    switch (manageOption)
    {
    case 1:
        createAcc();
        break;
    case 5:
        main();
        break;    
    default:
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

void createAcc(void)
{
    // Aux vars
    char *fullName = malloc(sizeof(char) * 255);
    char *email = malloc(sizeof(char) * 255);
    char *address = malloc(sizeof(char) * 255);
    int key;
    //system("clear");
    header();
    printf("\n");
    printf("\t\t\t[1] Create account.\n");
    printf("\n\n\n");
    printf("What's your full name?\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", fullName);
    printf("%s", fullName);
}
```

Comment: out of that `sizeof(char)`  values 1 by definition, useless to multiply by it. Why *menuOption* and *manageOption* are global vars ? `switch (menuOption)     { case 1:  manage();  break;  default: break; }` so complicated for nothing, just use a *if*

Comment: Note that `"%[^\n]s"` is a hybrid: Usually you'll want `"%[^\n]"` or `"%s"`.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic memory allocation for the strings? Why not use arrays?

Comment: And never call `main` from your own program. While it's not explicitly forbidden in C it's still bad. Use loops instead.

Comment: @user3121023 Flawless! Why the space and remove the s? I got that 254 = 254 chars and \0 (255)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks! Should change it!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've used dynamic memory allocation while learning how to use it. I don't know if there's some good practice or why use this than arrays.

Comment: The `s` is not part of the `%[]` format. It makes `scanf` look for and attempt to match an explicit `s` in the input. The leading space is to skip leading white-space from the input, like newlines left in the input buffer from previous inputs.

Comment: @bruno menuOption and manageOption should be called by other methods along the way. This is why I've made it global. About sizeof(char), I can change it to 255 instead? And I use switch because they case accept only integers.

Comment: @user3121023 Thank you for explanation.

Comment: `I can change it to 255 instead` yes. The gloval vars are not justified   in your case, their use is 'dangerous' and source of bugs

Comment: @bruno Thanks. I gonna read more about global vars and where to use it.

Answer (score 0):

it should be `"%[^\n]%*c"`